# Java Regexs: unexpected char: '('

Tags: java, regex, literals

I am using processing 1.0.6, which runs on java 1.6. I have the following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("func\((.*),(\-?[0-9\.]*),(\-?[0-9\.]*),(\-?[0-9\.]*)\)");
```

but it gives the error:

```
unexpected char: '('
```

and highlights the line I pasted above. If I change the offending `\(` to another character like `#`, it complains of the `\-` saying `unexpected char: '-'`. I should be able to use literals in a regex engine and it works in C#!

Comment: Nice working putting the crying/fat lip emoticon in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes too:

```
"func\\((.*),(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)\\)"
```

That string expression will the be evaluated to:

```
func\((.*),(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)\)
```

And that’s what you wanted.

Comment: Does java have something similar to C#'s @"literal string" notation?

Comment: C Rogers: no. As an aside: could MS have picked a worse name for that notation? "Literal string" as opposed to an ordinary "string literal". Ugh.

Comment: My mistake, they are called "string literals".

Comment: Looks like they're actually called "verbatim string literals" (as opposed to regular string literals). Sorry MS: that name isn't too bad after all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape \ in strings in Java by preceding it with a \, so

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("func\\((.*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*)\\)");
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `"\"` with `"\\"`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("func\\((.*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*)\\)");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java '(' and '-' is not an escape-required character. So '(' means '\' without any escape-required character that is why the error occur. The solution to this is the escepe that back-slash too:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("func\\((.*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*),(\\-?[0-9\\.]*)\\)");
```

If you need to use RegEx in both Java and C#, perhaps you should write a program that swap from one to another.

Comment: I've just recently moved from C# to Java (due to the excellent http://www.processing.org/ framework), so I am still getting used to the grammar/functionality changes.